# Market-maker's *ask* below current *bid*

Tags: trading, stock-markets, bid-ask, market-making, real-time-quotes

I am reviewing some market-maker raw data and sometimes I see the following happening. The market-maker quotes an ask price that is below the current bid price (of let's say, the market itself). How is that possible? What is happening?

An important characteristic of the quotes (ask) that are lower than the current bids, is that they are almost always at the same level. So even though the bid and ask are changing through time, these 'flawed' asks always remain on (approximately) the same price level.

Comment: https://www.investopedia.com/terms/c/crossedmarket.asp

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo This question does NOT refer to a crossed market situation, which never happens in modern markets. This question refers to the phenomenon described below by [Matthew](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/37469/market-makers-ask-below-current-bid/37470#37470).

Comment: Still looks crossed to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary purpose of the exchange is to execute asks against bids and to provide quotes of asks and bids

I suspect that what you're seeing is a divergence of the quoting system from the execution system in which the quote returned right before an execution making it appear as though there was a disparity. If the exchange did what every market participant depends on it to do, it executed the trade immediately after the quote was processed.

Comment: I thought this was it as well, but it's not. The quoted asks are WAY lower than the current bid/ask spread. For example bid/ask is 7.10/7.15 and the asks are quoted at 6.55. Something like that. And as all marketmarkers are obliged to offer at least the best bid/ask, this cannot be it.

Comment: Perhaps it's an artifact of options executing? What is your source data set?

Comment: It's not from options. It's just from plain stocks.

Comment: @Jean-Paul Market makers are not obliged to do anything.  **Registered** market makers are.  How do you know that the quote you're looking at is from a _registered_ market maker?

Comment: @dg99: I don't. I don't mean obliged in the sense of quoting the best bid/ask. I'm just saying: why would you quote an ask that is lower than the highest bid? It just doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Gotcha.  One reason would be user error (or user software error), but in *theory* the exchanges do not allow limit orders to appear in the book if they cross the spread.  Instead they get filled immediately (at the best available price).  However, exchanges and their software are far from perfect, and sometimes weird things happen.